# Is this language regular or non-regular : {ww | w ∈ {a,b}* } ∩ {a}*

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

I think it's a regular language but I can't find a DFA or a regular expression. Would anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: words in $\{ww\mid w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$ have even length.

Comment: Then it's regular, but I can't find a regular expression for this

Comment: Then how do you know it's regular? It might help to describe explicitly what your language is.

Comment: thinking a bit I realized that the first is not regular and the second is regular so the intersection of a regular language with a non-regular one gives a non-regular language. Hence {ww | w ∈ {a, b} *} ∩ {a} * is not regular right?

Comment: No, that's wrong. If $L$ is a non-regular language, then $L\cap \emptyset$ is regular and $L\cap \Sigma^*$ is not regular (but $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ are regular), so there is no general conclusion for the intersection of a regular and non-regular language.

Comment: Ok I understand, but in this case it gives a non-regular language right?

Comment: No it doesn't, the language is regular.

Comment: Think about it, what does a word composed of an even number of $a$'s look like?

Comment: A language with an even number of a's can be this w∈{a,b}, (b U a b * a)*. Right?

Comment: Ignore the $b$s. What does a language consisting entirely of strings of $a$s of even length look like? Regular or not?